# User-friendly, Form input that always totals 100

Tags: html, jquery, widget

I have a dynamically generated form that needs to gather several numerical values from a user that totals 100 (%). I thought about writing a script/algorithm that adjusts the remaining values of several text fields - so that when the user changes one value, the remaining values dynamically change (so that the values always total 100).

However, instead of text fields, I would really prefer something more user-friendly like sliders that move when one slider is adjusted or some other user-friendly widget (like an adjustable pie chart(?) that always totals 100%).

The script needs to work in late version of Firefox, Chrome and IE. I read somewhere that HTML5 sliders don't work in Firefox.

I am open to different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Am not getting your question clearly, assuming that you need a value slider which a person will slide and automatically the bar will increment every time by 1, so try using jQuery and Ajax, will suit your requirements, you can check out few over [here](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sliders work fine in FireFox - try http://www.colorpicker.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/), if you like. You can register a custom function on `change` event which easily adjusts the other sliders.

So in the end you got something like this (some pseudo-code in it):

```
$( "#slider1" ).slider({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
        var i = 100 - value_of_slider1 / number_of_sliders_remaining;
        $("#slider2).setValue(i);
        $("#slider3).setValue(i);
   }
});
```

Of course this can be implemented a lot more sophisticated. Just to give you the basic idea. Depends on your markup.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had problems with sliders in FireFox.

You can have the various sliders/input devices calculate on each other to get the output by division or whatever, then have the last/smallest number be subtracted rather than divided from the total. This way your other calculations will be accurate to the accuracy and the least significant value can make up the rest.